# how to apply css to extjs grid emptytext?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

Is there any special class applied to a grid's `emptyText`? I tried to check with Firebug inspecting the element and found only this:

```
<div id="gridview-1021" class="x-component x-grid-view x-fit-item x-component-default
 x-unselectable" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" style="-moz-user-select: none; width: 398px; height: 150px;">
There are no items to show in this view.
</div>
```

It seems like there is no special class to identify and apply CSS to `emptyText`. Is there any way to add a class, or a special way to style the empty text?

Note:

I did this and it worked nicely for me:

```
emptyText: '<div style="width:auto; text-align:center; padding-top:50px; color:red; font-weight:bold;">There are no items to show in this view.</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columns:[{
                header: 'columnName',
                dataIndex: 'dataIndex',
                renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex) {
                      if (value == '')
                        metaData.tdCls = 'emptyText'; 
                }
}]
```

And you should define emptyText css rule. This custom renderer applied to specific column

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?58604-How-to-center-emptyText-inside-grid-dataView) on Sencha forums:

Code:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  cls: 'my-grid',
  ...
});
```

CSS:

```
.my-grid .x-grid-empty {text-align: center; padding-top: <nnn>px;}
```

Comment: already tried that one problem is .x-grid-empty not apply. maybe extjs4 doesn't have that class on emptytext